# Operand between token and enum type

Tags: c++, struct, enums

```
   enum symbol {Number, Letter, Open_Bracket, Closed_Bracket, Unknown}

   struct token {
   string s;
   symbol v;
   };
```

Now, I want to write a function that returns false if a token t is unknown. I tried

```
bool check(token &t)
if (t == Unknown) 
return false;
```

But I know that it's wrong because t is a token and Unknown is a symbol. How can I make them of the same type?

I can't use the dot notation, because if I use

```
if (t.v == Unknown) return false;
```

I get this message

```
multiple definition of 't'
```

(I had forgotten to add the function parameter before.)

Comment: Did you mean to write `if (t.symbol == Unknown) `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access specific members of a structure using the `.` operator like this

`if(t.v == Unknown) return false`

As suggested in the comments you could also modify your structure and add a function that returns a boolean value.

```
struct token {
    string s;
    symbol v;
    bool checkUnknown(){
        return v == Unknown;
    }
};
```

And then you can do

```
if(t.checkSymbolUnknown()) return false;
```

Comment: Additionally, you can define a method that does exactly this, which would help your design more overall.

Example would be:

    bool check_unknown() const {
        return v == Unknown;
    }

Comment: @SenselessCoder: `isUnknown` would be better.

Comment: It probably would, you are right. In design naming is a bigger problem than coming up with the algorithm/code :P

Answer (score 3):

If you have a C++11 compiler, I would recommend to use [Scoped enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

```
enum class symbol {Number, Letter, Open_Bracket, Closed_Bracket, Unknown};

struct token {
   string s;
   symbol v;
};

// -----

if (t.v == symbol::Unknown)
    return false;
```